# Javascript + XML: Parsing text-only and mixed nodes (into JSON)

Tags: javascript, json, xml-parsing

I'm working on converting an XML document to a special JSON format using Javascript.

Using the standard DOM processing methods in Javascript, I need help constructing an efficient, elegant algorithm for determining whether a node contains any non-text nodes or attributes, and organizing the JSON object differently depending on the node contents.

**Example:**

```
<demo>
    <title>Text Test</title>
    <textonly id="demoText">
        This is a text-only node! It doesn't need a 'text' property.
    </textonly>
    <mixed id="aMixedNode">
        This is text
        <!-- This is a comment node -->
        <another />
        <!-- Note that this element has not 4, but 7 nodes -- counting the text between the non-text nodes! -->
        More text!
    </mixed>
    <textonly id="specialText" special="something">
        This would be a text-only node, but it's not because the attribute requires us to create a 'text' property
    </textonly>
    <textonly id="validText">This is a text node!</textonly>
    <nontext />
    <final>End of demo!</final>
</demo>
```

Should convert to:

```
{
    title: 'Text Test',
    demoText: 'This is a text-only node! It doesn't need a 'text' property.',
    aMixedNode: {
        text: [
            'This is text',
            'More text!'
        ],
        another: null
    },
    specialText: {
        special: 'something',
        text: 'This would be a text-only node, but it's not because the attribute requires us to create a 'text' property'
    },
    validText: 'This is a text node!',
    nonText: null,
    final: 'End of demo!'
}
```

**Notes:**

- All text values are trimmed; empty text values are removed/ignored
- Multiple text nodes, i.e. when text and other nodes are mixed, the text is stored in an array. If there's only one text value we just store it as a string.
- ID attributes are used as the property name if present; otherwise the node name is used. Multiple instances of the same node name, all with no ID, would be stored an array (but this is not demonstrated currently).
- Like empty text nodes, comment nodes are removed/ignored